# iOS: UILabel multi-line text get truncated in horizontal UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview

[image]

Issue:
UILabel multi-line text get truncated in horizontal UIStackView.

I have a horizontal UIStackView, in this stack view, the left side is an UIImage, right side is a UILabel with some text.

The UILabel is a multiline UILabel, it should wrap itself if text is very long. However, in runtime it got truncated.

Any ideas on how to fix it?
My code below:

```
self.imageView = self.createIconImageView(...)
self.textLabel.text = text
self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // which specify it is multi-line

let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.axis = .horizontal
stackView.alignment = .fill
stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
stackView.spacing = 8.0
stackView.addArrangedSubview(self.imageView)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(self.textLabel)

self.containerView.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.edgesToSuperview(insets: Style.containerInsets)
```

Comment: have a try `stackView.alignment = .center`

Comment: Feel free to post it as answer, I will mark it and make sure you get the scores. Thanks so much!! @Elevo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### alignment

```
/* The layout of the arrangedSubviews transverse to the axis;
 e.g., leading/trailing edges in a vertical stack
 */
@property(nonatomic) UIStackViewAlignment alignment;
```

---

For `.fill`

StackView will automatically generate these `layout attributes` for you.

```
 imageView.bottom == label.bottom
 imageView.top == label.top
```

the size of stackView depend on the 'voice' `image`'s size or size layout attributes of `imageView` as it is fixed instead of adjustable `UILable` which namely have the low priority.

---

For `.center`

StackView achieve a decent height by look for the max height between your `label` and `imageView`.

```
 _UILayoutSpacer.bottom >= imageView.bottom
 _UILayoutSpacer.bottom >= label.bottom
 _UILayoutSpacer.top <= imageView.top
 _UILayoutSpacer.top <= label.top
```